Deletion in van Emde Boas tree confusion
When we delete an item in a van Emde Boas tree we want to make sure we do only one recursive call in order to achieve $O(\log\log u)$ time complexity. This case confuses me:
If  the key x to be deleted is the min in a block, then we need to do two things. We need to set the new min to be the successor of x and we need to delete the successor from the data structure (as the min is not stored in the data structure). Why isn't this two recursive calls?

Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree#Delete not clear?

Page 105-106 from these lecture notes might also help.
